# can i use rest & wcf for backend site functionality securely?

Tags: .net, wcf, rest

in short i am building out the back-end part of my website and wanted to know whats the simplest way to get ajax asynchronous .net pages to interact with the server side in a secure method?

i am leaning towards rest and wcf but cant seem to solve how i would keep it secure. i will have client information and don't want one client to be able to pull another clients info.

my first hurdle is the actual login. i have the username/ password modal on the ui done and need to get a simple way to authenticate. looking at rest for this seems useless since the result will be in plain text.

what am i missing, this should be a cake walk. please someone set me straight with how to go about getting secure login and user data management working on a .net site.

Answer (score -1):

Check out [ASP.NET Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api). WCF has a lot of cruft around because it's designed to handle extremely complex web services and provide accessibility from all platforms. It also requires a considerable amount of configuration.

Web API, on the other hand, is designed specifically around HTTP and easy use via ajax. It gives you RESTful HTTP, HTTPS, simple XML, and Json. It "just works" without any configuration.

Comment: -1: as of .NET 4.0, WCF no longer requires much configuration for the most common scenarios.

Comment: Everything is relative. The minute you want to step out of one of those common scenarios (such as using HTTPS), you'll still need a lot more configuration than Web API.

Comment: i just want to log a user in, persist a user_id and name so i can make more calls to get data based on the user_id. And prevent other users from sending an ID not theirs to get someone else data